# Using python parser of ArcGIS field calculator to calculate field using information from subsequent row?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, field-calculator, python-parser

When using the field calculator, how do I get data from the subsequent row in  python?

Let's say I want to add a new field called head_diff. I want to take the current row's value for head, minus the subsequent row's value for head to get a head difference. Example for previous row:

```
for index, row in enumerate(rows,start=1):
    head_diff= !head! - row[index-1]
```

Someone suggested da.UpdateCursor, which looks promising. Will comment with procedure if I find a solution.

Comment: An option is to use the da.UpdateCursor (http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/arcpy-data-access/updatecursor-class.htm). It is like a more powerful Field Calculator

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour].  For questions that involve code we ask that you show us where you are stuck with your own code by including a [code snippet](http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/questions/4312) in your question.  There is an [edit] button beneath your question which will enable you to do that and a **`{}`** button that enables you to format any highlighted code nicely.

Comment: Why is this "on hold"? Seems like a legitmate question about row lookahead!?

Comment: @steloe Coding questions are expected to contain code. In fact, lookahead isn't possible, but caching the previous row is.